# React Native Error on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

Just had this error pop up for me

[image]

And then in the terminal

[image]

From what I can see it says there's a syntax error in `app/containers/index.js` and it expects a `{`?

All I'm doing in `app/containers/index.js` is exporting three components. The file looks like this

```
export NimbusNavigator from './Navigator/NimbusNavigator'
export SplashContainer from './Splash/SplashContainer'
export AppContainer from './App/AppContainer'
```

That's it. So I'm not exactly sure what the error is referring to. This is my first time using React Native with Android but I had experienced something weird w/ iOS where I had to reset the cache b/c it was telling me a folder didn't exist that clearly did. I reset the cache and it worked fine. I tried that here but I'm still getting the same error. I doubled checked spelling and everything as well so not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!